# Is it possible to convert date/time in Excel such as "Mon Nov 11 2019 22:12:22"?

Tags: excel, date, time

Is it possible to convert a date/time in Excel such as Mon Nov 11 2019 22:12:22 UTC time to and EST date/time value?  Essentially subtract 5 hours from it? Some of the formulas I've been playing with are:

```
=C2-5/24
=(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,27),"T"," "))+(MID(A1,28,3)/24)
```

Comment: I've tried several date/time formulas, to no avail.

Comment: please share some sample data and demonstrate the expected result accordingly.

Comment: What is the output shown for the `=C2-5/24` formula? Try formatting the cell as date/time